# Self-Hosted Photo Sharing Tool for Debian

Tags: debian, apt, repository

Searching the web you can find a lot of self-hosted photo sharing tools. Just to name a few open source projects:

- NextCloud
- Photoprism
- Piwigo
- Lychee
- LibrePhotos
- Coppermine
- MediaGoblin
- Uber Gallery
- ZenPhoto
- Robroy
- Photoview
- Chevereto
- Photato
- PhotoFloat
- Photonix
- Hugo Split Gallery Theme

However, looking at the Debian repo, I could not found any photo sharing tool !!

**Question**

1. Is there really no photo sharing tool at the Debian repo? If so, why?

<strike>2. Any tool recommendation?</strike>

Comment: What defines a "photo sharing tool"? If all you want to do is make image files accessible from the web, `httpd`/`apache2` will do. If not, you need to be much more specific (and ask softwarerecs.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @Panki `> httpd/apache2 will do.`: Yeah, I considered that too. Any simple way to allow users to comment the photos?

Comment: @Panki `> ask softwarerecs.stackexchange.com`: The focus of the question is not exactly a software recommendation. But why there is none available in the Debian's repo although there is a plethora of open source projects out there.